# Difference between Ajax.BeginForm and Handling Html.BeginForm through Custom AJAX

Tags: jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc-3

I just wanted to know what is the exact difference between the below codes.

**Ajax.BeginForm Way**

```
@using (Ajax.BeginForm("foo", "home", new AjaxOptions { OnSuccess = "onSuccess" }))
{
@Html.EditorFor(x => x.SomeProperty)
<button type="submit">OK</button>
}
```

**Html.BeginForm way**

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("foo", "home", FormMethod.Post, new { id = "myform" }))
{
@Html.EditorFor(x => x.SomeProperty)
<button type="submit">OK</button>
}

$(function() {
$('#myform').submit(function(){
    $.ajax({
        url: this.action,
        type: this.method,
        data: $(this).serialize(),
        success: function(result) {
            alert(result.Foo);
        }
    });
    return false;
});
});
```

Comment: The former is more concise, the latter gives you complete control of the JS used to create and handle the AJAX request.

Comment: check it will get more clear for you http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/429164/Html-BeginForm-vs-Ajax-BeginForm-in-MVC